# How to Import a Solution With a Plugin Steps registered against a Custom Action?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I'm attempting to push a plugin registration step from my local environment to Dev, but I'm getting this erorr on import:

> "sdkmessage with Id = {Guid} Does Not Exist"

No matter what I do, I can't figure out how to import it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very specific bug that was fixed with CRM 2013 SP1 UR 2.  But if you aren't there yet, I blogged about the issue and the steps to fix it:  [How to Import a Solution With a Custom Action and a Plugin Step Registered Against the Custom Action in CRM 2013 SP 1 UR 1](http://www.dotnetdust.blogspot.com/2015/02/how-to-import-solution-with-custom.html)

It's not a fun fix, but it is possible.